# Delete and update Outlook contact using jacob library

Tags: java, outlook, jacob

I am using jacob library. Using jacob library and following [this](http://aashuaggarwal.blogspot.com/2011/11/accessing-outlook-contacts-using-jacob.html) tutorial i am able to add a contact in outlook. Now i want to delete and update that contact using jacob. i want to know is there any way to delete the outlook contact using jacob.

I am using this code to add contact in outlook. here email id is unique id.

```
        ActiveXComponent axOutlook = new ActiveXComponent("Outlook.Application");
        Dispatch oOutlook = axOutlook.getObject();
        Dispatch createContact = Dispatch.call((Dispatch)oOutlook, "CreateItem", new Variant(2)).toDispatch();

        Dispatch.put(createContact,"LastName",cont.getLastName());
        Dispatch.put(createContact,"FirstName",cont.getFirstName());
        Dispatch.put(createContact,"Title",cont.getTitle());
        Dispatch.put(createContact,"Email1Address",cont.getPrimaryEmail());

        Dispatch.call(createContact, "Save");
```

Comment: I have been looking through the source to find an answer to your question but it looks very poorly documented.

Comment: my question is poorly documented??

Comment: No the documentation for the JACOB library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JACOB is a very thin wrapper around COM IDispatch calls, so if you want to know how to do *any* particular task in Outlook the starting point would be the official [Outlook Object Model documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862373.aspx)

Your particular case, locating and deleting a contact, is performed through

```
namespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
contactsFolder = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
contact = contactsFolder.items.find( "[Email1Address] = 'mail@server.com' )

if (contact != null)
{
    contact.Delete
}
```

The second half of the work is translating these calls to JACOB-speak. Assuming you have located your contact item, the code would be something like

```
ActiveXComponent outlookApplication = new ActiveXComponent("Outlook.Application");
Dispatch namespace = outlookApplication.getProperty("Session").toDispatch();

Dispatch contactsFolder = Dispatch.call(namespace, "GetDefaultFolder", new Integer(10)).toDispatch();
Dispatch contactItems = Dispatch.get(contactsFolder, "items");
String filter = String.format("[Email1Address] = '%s'", cont.getPrimaryEmail());
Dispatch contact = Dispatch.call(contactItems, "find", filter);

if (contact != null)
{
    Dispatch.call(contactItem, "Delete");
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to locate an contact from outlook using jacob??

Comment: If you extend your question with exactly HOW (name? some other unique property? did you store the entryID when you added the contact?) you want to locate your contact, preferably with OOM code, I'll gladly add the additional information to this answer.

Comment: Thanks you are the only one who solved my problem. thanks again